# Clock only shows up on Prime Monitor?

Tags: gnome, multiple-monitors, panel

So one personal complaint I have about Ubuntu is that the clock only shows up on the primary monitor. And I'd love to have it on the none-prime monitor.

This sounds great in theory. The problem, is that your primary monitor will more then likely be in fullscreen mode when playing video games, watching videos or doing anything really. That is after all the entire point of a dual monitor setup, to be more productive even while in fullscreen mode.

This effectively renders the clock and panel completely useless for about 90 percent of the time. I don't know what developer thought this was a great idea, because it's absolutely terrible.

Answer (score 0):

You likely need to install the extension https://github.com/spin83/multi-monitors-add-on to get top panel on additional monitors, then you should be able to add a clock (or other components as you wish) onto the new panel on the second screen.